# How can I debug any program with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Windows offers me the possibility do debug a program with Visual Studio 2010 when an "unhandled exception" or another program fault occurs. However, I would like to debug a program I have written in VB6 with Visual Studio 2010, even when it does not trigger an error.   I want to see the assembly code and step through it, view the stack contents and similar things. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run the ide and attach the process. when you pause debugging session, you may see the assembly.

otherwise, you can use ollydbg, ida, or such dissassembles to view the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Debug > Attach to Process command.

Comment: Can you open a vb6 project in Visual Studio? I don't think so, which means you can't step though the code.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: It looks like VB6 produces .pdb files if you compile with debug information. Visual Studio can pull line-number information out of a .pdb even if it came from a different language (I've done it with binaries built by Delphi for .NET). So the answer is, no you couldn't open the VB6 project in Visual Studio, but you could debug it if you attach to the running process.

Answer (score 1):

VB6 assembly will not be meaningful, as VB6 is a (sometimes) Interpreted language. However, if you still want to do this, the Debugging Tools for Windows (WinDbg) is a far better tool for this task.

Comment: VB6 is a compiled language, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240843(v=vs.60).aspx – how meaningful the code is to me is an entirely different issue, though …

Comment: Not always: "P-code, or pseudo code, is an intermediate step between the high-level instructions in your Basic program and the low-level native code your computer's processor executes. At run time, Visual Basic translates each p-code statement to native code. By compiling directly to native code format, you eliminate the intermediate p-code step."

Comment: windbg is generally more useful that the debugger integrated into MSVS